# Ignore a property from being serialized when trying to serialize an object to Json using JIL (like [JsonIgnore] in newtonsoft)

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, jil

I've recently changed my Json serialization/deserialization logic from **Newtonsoft** to **JIL**,it(Jil) works with better performance than newtonsoft (as expected) but I have one major problem with it

My model objects are usually **big objects with lots of properties** including their own props and their parent props, so **I can't pass the whole object to the client on every request**, I usually **exclude some of their properties** (unnecessary ones).

In newtonsoft I easily **used `JsonIgnore` attribute** and my need was satisfied but as I googled a bit I haven't found it's **(JsonIgnore)** equivalent attribute in JIL.

Does this attribute exists in JIL or I should write it myself??

if the answer is no **how can I write an attribute that Ignores property from being serialized with JIL** because I have no access to JIL `JSON.Serialize` mechanism

any help would be hugely appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself I should **use JilDirective attribute with first property of false** see below

```
[JilDirective(true)]
```